# How populate column in pandas dataframe with column names where value meets condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I need a new column in dataframe populated with column names where a specified condition is met. It is `> 1` in this example.

I've tried to iterate through columns in question (it's a subset of `df.columns`), but doesn't provide the desired output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 2],
    [2, 2, 1, 1]],
  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
cols = df.columns[:-1]
df['d'] = ''
for col in cols:
    df.loc[df[col] > 1, 'd'] = col
```

Current output:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 0, 2, 2, 'col3'],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, ''],
    [0, 2, 3, 2, 'col3'],
    [2, 2, 1, 1, 'col2']],
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'd'])
```

What I need is info about all columns that meet that condition, so output like this:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 0, 2, 2, 'col3'],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, ''],
    [0, 2, 3, 2, 'col2,col3'],
    [2, 2, 1, 1, 'col1,col2']],
    columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'd'])
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 df['d'] = (df.iloc[:,:-1] > 1).apply(lambda x: ','.join([col for cond,col in zip(x,df.columns) if cond]), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4          d
0     1     0     2     2       col3
1     1     1     0     0           
2     0     2     3     2  col2,col3
3     2     2     1     1  col1,col2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following snippet.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 2],
    [2, 2, 1, 1]],
  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
# cols = df.columns[:-1]

df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1]
df1['threshold']=1

df2 = df1.drop('threshold', 1).gt(df1['threshold'], 0)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.index[x]),axis=1)

df['d']=df2

print df
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4           d
0     1     0     2     2        col3
1     1     1     0     0            
2     0     2     3     2  col2, col3
3     2     2     1     1  col1, col2
```